# Getting double square brackets while retriving data from map

Tags: java

I am storing data inside a Map in form of String as key and  JSONArray as Value 
But while retrieving data i am getting double square brackets for value

This is my program

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<String, JsonArray> datafromdb = new LinkedHashMap<String, JsonArray>();

        JsonArray jsonarray = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject pacs_obj = new JsonObject();
        pacs_obj.addProperty("pac_id", "1235");
        jsonarray.add(pacs_obj);
        String new_catid = "1";

        if (!datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
            datafromdb.put(new_catid, new JsonArray());
        }

        datafromdb.get(new_catid).add(jsonarray);

        Iterator it = datafromdb.entrySet().iterator();
        JsonArray catarr = new JsonArray();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();

            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) pair.getValue();

            System.out.println(array);

        }

    }

}
```

when i run the above program the out put is

```
[[{"pac_id":"1235"}]]
```

Could you please tell me how to retrieve this issue

Comment: Your code contains a JsonArray which contains a JsonArray which contains a JsonObject, so that is entirely expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two square braces, because you've created two arrays:
Here:

```
JsonArray jsonarray = new JsonArray();
JsonObject pacs_obj = new JsonObject();
pacs_obj.addProperty("pac_id", "1235");
jsonarray.add(pacs_obj);
```

and here:

```
if (!datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
    datafromdb.put(new_catid, new JsonArray());
}
datafromdb.get(new_catid).add(jsonarray);
```

Just get rid of one of array, for example:

```
if (!datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
    datafromdb.put(new_catid, jsonarray);
}
```

Comment: I think that `put` call would need to be done without an `if` (based on the limited context provided in the question).

Comment: thanks a lot , but A single new_catid can contain multiple jsonarrays so the reason i have added that .